# loop or iterate to determine if all columns from multiple datasets have the same name and position in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multiple-columns, names

I have 15 datasets or data frames, let them be named `data_1` to `data_15`. All suppose to have the same columns names. I would like to check if all **columns have the same name and position** before concatenate them. I concatenated them and I ended with an extra column because one column name of one dataset was misspelled. I used the following following code per dataset, but I would like to improve my skills and save time.

```
print(list(data_1))
```

The code I use to concatenate all datasets is the following:

```
pd.concat([data_1; data_2...data_15])
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If all the dataframes *"have the same columns names"*, why do you need to check their column names ?

Comment: they suppose to have the same names, but usually there are mistakes. I mentioned it

Comment: In your question, we read this: *"All have same columns names, but differ in number of rows."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the dataframes in a list, then use `all()` to test if the column names are all the same.

```
columns = list(data_1.columns.values)
df_list = [data_2, ..., data_15]

if all(list(df.columns.values) == columns for df in df_list):
    # code that concatenates all the dataframes
else:
    print("Columns don't match")
```

Comment: I got the following `ValueError: the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to convert to lists.

Answer (score 0):

first create df comprised of column labels = df1, df2, df3...df15, with the values of each column being the column names of each dataframe

Each index position in your new df will coincide with the actual position of this column label in each of your 15 original dfs. In my example below, I've use only 7 dfs for simplicity and the df columns names are different colors.

col_names = a = pd.DataFrame(

{'df1': df1.columns,

'df2': df2.columns,

'df3': df3.columns,

'df4': df4.columns,

'df5': df5.columns,

'df6': df6.columns,

'df7': df7.columns})

[image]

This will give you a nice overview of all the column labels per df and how they compare in position to your other dfs.  You can then apply boolean masks to return an indexed series (also coinciding with the position of the column names) of True/False values according to whether or not the column names match:

```
col_names.df1 == col_names.df2
```

[image]